# Writing a sqlite3 table to csv

Tags: python, csv, sqlite

I am struggling to create a function in python which takes a table name and outputs a CSV (comma-separated) with the contents of this table. My code thus far is as follows:

```
def tableWriter(tableName): 
    with open('table.csv', 'wb') as f: 
        writer = csv.writer(f) 
        for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM '"+tableName+"'"): 
            writer.writerows(row)
```

I keep having errors getting the table name from the function definition passed to the execute statement and have followed the API so I'm not sure where else to turn.

Comment: '"+tableName+"' There's your issue. In SQL table names are NOT considered strings and enclosed by quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

You are enclosing the tablename in quotes; that makes it a *string literal* in SQL, not a table reference. Perhaps you wanted to use double quotes, backticks or square brackets instead? See [SQL As Understood By SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) on the SQLite website for a quick overview of the difference:

> `'keyword'`
>   A keyword in single quotes is a string literal.
>
> `"keyword"`
>   A keyword in double-quotes is an identifier.
>
> `[keyword]`
>   A keyword enclosed in square brackets is an identifier. This is not standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MS Access and SQL Server and is included in SQLite for compatibility.
>
> `` `keyword` ``
>   A keyword enclosed in grave accents (ASCII code 96) is an identifier. This is not standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MySQL and is included in SQLite for compatibility.

The following, using string formatting instead of concatenation, should work:

```
def tableWriter(tableName): 
    with open('table.csv', 'wb') as f: 
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        c.execute('SELECT * FROM "{0}"'.format(tableName)
        writer.writerows(c)
```

There is no need to loop over the result rows; `writer.writerows()` does this for you.